# React not state not updating first time

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

So this is my code:

```
const [module, setModule] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=> {

async function getModuleInfo(){
        let ModuleInfo = await firebase 
        .firestore()
        .collection('Modules')
        .doc('PBS1Module1')
        .get();
        if (!ModuleInfo.exists){
          console.log('geen module info')
        } else {
          let ModuleInfov2 = ModuleInfo.data();
          setModule(ModuleInfov2)
     
        }} getModuleInfo()
    console.log(module)
}, [])
```

When I go to this screen, the first log is an empty array. Then when I remove the `console.log()` and save it and than change it back to `console.log(module)` it gives me the data I need.

What am I doing wrong? All my import statements are good because those are working.

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you are logging out the value `module` inside the useEffect hook you now have a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). When the component initially renders, the value of `module` is `[]` so that is what is passed to the closure inside `useEffect`. When you update the state via the `setModule` function, React will rerender the component with the updated state and you get the expected value. To help understand this, try moving your `console.log` outside of the `useEffect`. This will make it run every time the component renders, as opposed to now where it only runs on the first render since your dependency array on the `useEffect` hook is empty.

I tested with the below example and when running it I get logs in the following order:

```
fresh data is:  null
stale data is:  null
fresh data is:  (4) [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const fetchData = async () => {
  return [1, 2, 3, 4, ]
}

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const asyncFetch = async () => {
      const data = await fetchData();
      setData(data);
    }
    asyncFetch();
    console.log("stale data is: ", data);
  }, []);
  console.log("fresh data is: ", data);
  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}
```